# Get location of div on grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am making a board game I am looking for a better way to manage the pieces on the board. What I have now is a way to place them on a board from coordinates. This is the JSON object that stores the player data:

```
"players" : {
    "1" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "name": "ilya",
        "units" : [
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "row" : 1,
                "square" : 2
            },{
                "id" : 2,
                "row" : 2,
                "square" : 1
            },{
                "id" : 3,
                "row" : 3,
                "square" : 1
            }
        ]
    },
```

And I simply place them by creating a div and appending it to the corresponding board square div and move them around with jquery-ui:

```
$('<div/>', {
    class: 'draggable player' + player + ' unit unit' + unit,
}).appendTo('.row' + row + ' .square' + square + ' .unitPosition');
```

`row` and `square` are a table and `unitPosition` is a helper class within `square`

Now to get back the data after the player has moves I can get back the row and square classes and extract their numbers, but it seems to me a very inefficient way. Is there a better way to manage such a grid and store the location data of each piece/unit?

by popular request, this is the html (shortened for the example):

```
<div id="board">
    <div class="clearfix row row1">
        <div class="square square1">
            <div class="unitPosition"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square square2">
            <div class="unitPosition"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square square3">
            <div class="unitPosition"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix row row2">
        <div class="square square1">
            <div class="unitPosition"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square square2">
            <div class="unitPosition"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square square3">
            <div class="unitPosition"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the board:
[image]

Comment: Which data exactly you're trying to get after each move? The player id? Looks like a good use case for html5 data attributes, or the jquery data object.

Comment: @bfavaretto I want the position of each unit in row/column

Comment: @ATOzTOA I want to know if there is a better way then to work with classes and taking `square1` and extracting the `1`. Maybe some way to predefined the grid data and not using DOM scanning to get it

Comment: How do the user places/moves the pieces?

Comment: @ATOzTOA the user drags them. I use jquery UI draggable & droppable and they are re-appended to the corresponding `.unitPosition`

Comment: One alternative is to use the mouse coordinates, but then also you will need array to store the coordinates of each cell.

Comment: is objective to update the original data object?  really not totally clear what issue is. Picture is pretty but real html would be a big help instead. Also very easy to use `index()` for row and cell

Comment: @charlietfl yes! The goal is to update the original data object. How can index() help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to update the data object it would make it a little simpler if you change `units` to an object instead of array using the `id` as key for each element

```
"players" : {
    "1" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "name": "ilya",
        "units" : {
            1: {
                "id" : 1,
                "row" : 1,
                "square" : 2
            },
            2:{
                "id" : 2,
                "row" : 2,
                "square" : 1
            }        
    }
```

You can use `index()` method to get row and cell indexes. Using `data-` attributes for each element will help a lot.

When you read the data you can find the cell using `eq()` based on the values of `row` and `squre` in your data.

```
var $cell = $('tr').eq( row ).find('td').eq( square);
$('<div data-player="'+player.id+'" data-unit_id="'+unit+'"/>', {
    class: 'draggable player' + player + ' unit unit' + unit,
}).appendTo($cell);
```

When you drop the unit in a new square:

```
/* pseudo code, not sure what your drop/append code looks like*/

var $cell= /* your logic to define the cell being placed in*/
var square= $cell.index();
var row= $cell.parent().index();
/* read player and unit from "data-" attributes of DIV*/
var unit= $(this).data('unit_id'), player= $(this).data('player');
```

Now with revised data structure it is very easy to update the main object `players`:

```
players[player].units[unit].row=row;
players[player].units[unit].square=square;
```

Simple Cell/Row Index demo: http://jsfiddle.net/buh4h/

API References:

http://api.jquery.com/index/

http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 1):

We don't know much about your code, but you seem to want to have a way to attach data to HTML elements, without having to rely on classes, and extracting numbers from class names.

You could add `data-` attributes to each table cell and player divs to separate the data, instead of (or in addition to) using classes. Your HTML would become something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-row="1" data-col="1">
            <div data-player="1"></div>
        </td>
        <!-- etc -->
    </tr>
    <!-- etc -->
</table>
```

Then you can retrieve those values with jQuery by reading those attributes, or using the `.data()` method:

```
// Assuming you're inside an event handler and "this" is a td
var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
// or
var row = $(this).data('row');
```